# Code not executing sequentially

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

For some reason, this code is not executing sequentially. Xcode seems to be evaluating the if-else statement and then displaying the `UIAlertView` that is in the if-else statement before displaying the `UIAlertView` that is before the if-else statements.

Below is my code for your reference:

```
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender; {
    //self.tbxUsername.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vmcv"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email"
                                                    message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", acc.Email]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


    if([self.tbxUsername.text isEqualToString:acc.Email ])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication"
                                                        message: @"Success"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication"
                                                        message: @"Fail"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not show multiple UIAlertView sequentially like this. You need to wait until the previous one is dismissed and then present the new one in the delegate callback.

You will want to be able to identify which UIAlertView is calling the delegate method, so set up some properties to hold your UIAlertViews.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *emailAlertView, *successAlertView, *failureAlertView;
```

When your button is pushed you will only launch the first UIAlertView asking for their email. Make sure you updated your code to set the delegate to self and that your view controller implements the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol.

```
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender; {
    self.tbxUsername.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vmcv"];

    self.emailAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email"
                                                    message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", acc.Email]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [self.emailAlertView show];
}
```

Now implement the delegate method to show the next UIAlertView only once the first one has been dismissed.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(alertView == self.emailAlertView) {
        if([self.tbxUsername.text isEqualToString:acc.Email])
        {
            self.successAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication"
                                                            message: @"Success"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [self.successAlertView show];
        }
        else
        {
            self.failureAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication"
                                                            message: @"Fail"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [self.failureAlertView show];
        }
    }
    else if(alertView == self.successAlertView) {
        //handle dismiss event of success alert view
    }
    else if(alertView == self.failureAlertView) {
        //handle dismiss event of failure alert view
    }
}
```

This should achieve the "sequential" effect that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. objective-c really seems v different from the languages i did before such as c# and java.

Comment: The delegation pattern shown above is a very common design pattern used in Objective-C and throughout the iOS SDK. Good iOS developers become familiar with it and embrace it in their own code. To get more hands on experience with delegation, try to implement and customize a UITableView. UITableView has both a delegate and a datasource protocol that should help you learn more about this design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing doesn't take place in real time. You issue the drawing commands, and the screen actually gets drawn in the event loop after you fall out of your method.  You can't step through and see your screen get updated.  So you need to show the first alert, exit your method, than have the second alert called from the exit method (button pushed) in the first alert.

Comment: Hi, sorry but i'm unfamiliar with objective-c. i was wondering if you could illustrate what you meant through some skeleton codes? thanks alots!